# Docker "unable to calculate image disk size"

Tags: docker, windows-subsystem-for-linux, docker-desktop

When running docker desktop, it starts for 2 seconds and then closes.

I have tried reinstalling and changing the configuartion but nothing has worked so far.

Answer (score 11):

I just had the same error today. I cannot be sure it is the same problem that you have so you must check first. I was getting the message "unable to calculate the disk image size" in the UI and not being able to execute any docker command to prune it (https://docs.docker.com/config/pruning/) since the daemon was down. I also updated docker to the latest version and the error was still there. I am supposing you are using Docker Desktop for Windows over WSL 2.

The first step was to execute the self diagnostic tool (https://docs.docker.com/desktop/troubleshoot/overview/#self-diagnose-tool)

```
C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\resources\com.docker.diagnose.exe check
```

Just to find out the following error message (and a few others that can be related, so I ignored them): "WSL Distribution docker-desktop is missing"

[Distribution error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mmONa.png)

So, I checked the WSL list using the wsl --list --verbose command and the docker-desktop distribution was in the "Uninstalling" state.

Following the advice here (even it is not for the same error) https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/6971#issuecomment-636358053 which ensures it will be recreated, I executed wsl --unregister docker-desktop and started the docker engine again and everything started without errors.

[wsl and docker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qayqH.png)

I am not sure what caused it, but it was certainly not disk space.

Answer (score 0):

In my case what helped was: uninstalling Docker, unregistering both Docker containers from `wsl`, removing `Docker` and `Docker Desktop` from `%APPDATA%` and reinstalling Docker.

Answer (score -1):

I experienced a similar problem and here is what I did.

First I ran the following command

```
$ wsl -l -v
  NAME                   STATE           VERSION
* Ubuntu                 Running         2
  docker-desktop         Stopped         2
  docker-desktop-data    Stopped         2
```

Then I just unregister all distros like that

```
wsl --unregister docker-destop
wsl --unregister docker-destop-data
wsl --unregister ubuntu
```

And again installed ubuntu

```
wsl --install ubuntu
```

After all this, just launched the docker desktop. And it started

Answer (score -4):

docker system prune
this worked for me

Comment: Have already tried to prune but unfortunately did not work for me.

Comment: docker system prune -a

Comment: This gave another error "error during connect: This error may indicate that the docker daemon is not running." Could not find an answer to this problem aswell so im kinda stuck in a loop right now.

Comment: open cmd as admin and run:  
"C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\DockerCli.exe" -SwitchDaemon

Comment: If Docker Desktop isn't starting up, you won't be able to run any `docker` commands.